# BeautifulSoup not selecting new elements in datepicker after month change

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, beautifulsoup

I am trying to select the same day in the next month from a datepicker using selenium and beautifulsoup but beautifulsoup is always getting the date elements for the starting month. The datepicker holds all the days as `<td>` so I use `find_all('td')` and run a for loop to check if the current date of the next month is already visible. If not, I click the next month button with selenium and find the element with another loop.

```
# activating datepicker. need to select the date now
driver.find_element_by_name("datepicker").click()

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')
calendar = bsObj.find_all('td')

today_index = -1
searching = True

# check if there are 30 days on the visible calendar after the current day
for i in range(len(calendar)):
    calendar[i] = calendar[i].div
    print calendar[i].text
    if day == calendar[i].text and searching:
        today_index = i
        searching = False

print calendar

# if there are 30 days left, select the day on the calendar
if (len(calendar) - today_index) >= 30:
    thirty_from_today = calendar[today_index + 30]
# if there are not 30 days left, move to next month and find 30th day from today
else:
    searching = True
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("*[title='Next month']").click()
    next_month_calendar = bsObj.find_all('td')
    print 'MOVING TO NEXT MONTH', next_month_calendar
    for i in range(len(next_month_calendar)):
        next_month_calendar[i] = next_month_calendar[i].div
        print next_month_calendar[i].text
        if day == next_month_calendar[i].text and searching:
            searching = False
            print 'setting thirty_from_today variablr too', next_month_calendar[i]
            thirty_from_today = next_month_calendar[i]
```

I can see that the next_month_calendar variable is still showing all the days in march (and some before and after because the datepicker shows a bit more than one month at a time) even after I activate the next month button to show the days in April, but I don't understand why because I can see the datepicker change to April as selenium controls my browser. I can tell that the dates are definitely wrong because each `<td>` element has a date-data element in Unix time.

Comment: Where do you get the variable `pageSource` from?

Comment: I get it from webdriver.get(urlhere). The response has a page source property which is the HTML of the page.

Comment: I guess the problem is you get the page source before you click the 'datepicker'. Could you try to get the page source after clicking the 'datepicker'?